# PrimeFaces chart

Tags: primefaces

i am using primefaces 3.0 in my project, i have implemented the chart in testing1.xhtml, but that page content needs to display on main.xhtml, but the chart not rendering very first time. the chart rendering after giving the refresh only, but it should not come like this .. i have attached the model snippet for ur reference.. pls kindly help me to fix this issue..

testing1.xhtml

```xml
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
      xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
       xmlns:portlet="http://java.sun.com/portlet"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">

      <h:form id="testForm">

      <p:lineChart id="testChart"  value="#{testBean.chart}"
      style="float:left; margin-top:150px; border:0px; margin-left:0px; padding:0px; height:140px; width:230px; "/> 
    <h:form>

</ui:composition>
```

i am calling this page from main.xhtml

main.xhtml

```xml
    <body onLoad="loadData();" >

        <h:panelGrid style="height:33px;"/>
        <h:form style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
    <p:remoteCommand name="loadData" action="#{testBean.chartLoad}"  update="testChart" />

 <p:panel  style="height:auto; width:238px;" id="testPanel" header="Testing" closable="false" toggleable="true">
              <ui:include src="testing1.xhtml"/>
            </p:panel>
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: My suggestion to you is to not use primefaces charts, Primefaces chart consist full of bugs, Instead of it use highcharts. Link : http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: @Jo_bast PrimeFaces charts is 99% jqplot. If you make such a bold statement, then at least provide links to all these bugs\

Answer (score 2):

looks look a nested `form` issue...

try to remove the `<h:form id="testForm">` from within your inner page , cause its already surrounded by `form` tag from outer page...

Answer (score 1):

Just add these lines in page. There is a bug in loading js/css

```
<h:outputScript name="charts/charts.js" library="primefaces" />

<h:outputStylesheet name="charts/charts.css" library="primefaces" />
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me.
I use charts in a ui:composition.

Answer (score 0):

Remove  tag from testing1.xhtml. Since your main page has a h:form tag you don't have to add another tag inside your ui:include.

And even if it isn't working then add an ID to  and add update=":< yourGivenFormID >" in p:lineChart

Answer (score 0):

Remove the form tag in testing1.xhtml

Add in head section of the testing1.xhtml page the following:

```
<h:head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/javax.faces.resource/charts/charts.css.jsf?ln=primefaces"/>
    ......
</h:head>
```

Comment: why is this needed I cannot imagine removing the form tag solves this problem for the initial rendering... It is not good, that is true, but not for this problem imo. And your answer is a combination of two other answers were using the `outputStylesheet` is a better suggestion

Comment: It works for me at least. I agree that outputStylesheet works too and maybe is more elegant